# How to hide an element if another element contains any text

Tags: hide

How do I write the following in jquery:

```
<div class="one">Hello I am One</div>
<div id="hello"></div>
```

If `.one` contains any text then hide `hello`?

Thank you very much!

Comment: This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you for the answers! This worked for me:

```
if($('.one').text() == '') {
    $('#hello').hide;
}
```

Comment: TJ Fogarty's CSS answer is better, and its answered a few days back, why dont you accept his answer? Also his JavaScript solution will work.

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript:

```
<script>
var txt = document.getElementsByClassName('one')[0].innerText;
if(txt == "") {
    document.getElementById('hello').style.display = "none";
}
</script>
```

## jQuery:

```
<script>
if($('.one').text() == '') {
   $('#hide').hide(0);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find the length of text in a given element, and if the length is 0 then you know it's empty.

```
var one = document.querySelectorAll('.one')[0];
var hello = document.getElementById('hello');

if (one.innerText.length) {
  hello.style.display = 'none';
}
```

Alternatively, you could accomplish this with just CSS if #hello appears right after .one.

```
#hello {
  display: none;
}

.one:empty + #hello {
  display: block;
}
```